# como aumentar los valor de varios inputs, en un contador, con sus botones correspondientes de incremento y decremento? javascript

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un form con 5 inputs y sus botones de incremento y decremento, quiero sumarle o restarle 1 numero cada vez que clickeo el boton de cada input , pero cuando le paso un forEach me toma solo el valor del 1er input y todos los botones suman y restan el mismo input

```
      <form class="form_user" id="form_user">


                    <label class="label" id="label" for="Horas">Horas</label>
                    <button id="btnSignos" class="btnSignos">-</button><input class="input_form" id="grupoInput"
                        type="number"  placeholder="0" autofocus min="0" value="25"><button
                        class="btnSignos2" id="btnSignos2">+</button>

                    <label class="label" >Horas2</label>
                    <button class="btnSignos">-</button><input class="input_form" id="grupoInput2" type="number"
                         placeholder="0" min="0" value="15"><button class="btnSignos2">+</button>


                

                    <button class="cerrarModal" id="cerrarModal"><strong>Cancelar</strong></button>
                    <input type="button" name="send" class="send_btnForm" id="send_btn" value="Anotar">

                </form>
```

este es el Javascript, donde realice un delegation y un forEach por cada input, pero me sigue dando undefined en el mostrador solo del lado de la consola, al utilizar el queryselector.input me toma el valor, pero al realizar el queryselectorAll.input[0].value, me toma los datos del array pero no del arreglo completo y se desactivan los botones

```
           let btnMas = document.querySelectorAll('.btnSignos2')
        let btnMenos = document.querySelectorAll('.btnSignos')
        let mostrador = document.querySelectorAll('.input_form');
        let mostrador2 = document.querySelector('grupoInput2');


        let numero = 0;


       btnMas.forEach(function (btn) {

      btn.addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
      event.preventDefault();


     if(numero === 99) {
    numero == 99;
    }else{
    numero++;
    mostrador.value = numero;
   //  mostrador2.value = numero;
   }

  })
 });


   mostrador.forEach(function(e) {
   console.log(e.value);
  })




  btnMenos.forEach(function (btn) {

  btn.addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
  event.preventDefault();
  if(numero === 0) {
    numero == 0;
      }else{
        numero--;
          mostrador.value = numero;
       }
      })
     });
```

Comment: Buenas noches Joaquin, te sugiero leer [ask].
En general lo ideal es enviar código mínimo verificable, así podemos ver lo que intentas hacer, hacer las pruebas pertinentes y ayudarte en el menor tiempo posible.

Comment: Falta lo más importante. El código javascript.

Comment: Gracias por las sugerencias y la paciencia...ahi edite el codigo... es la 1er vez que pregunto en esta plataforma, si tiene alguna ayuda les agradeceria

Comment: Puedes crear un [repro] en la pregunta misma a través de un snippet, insertándolo con el botón que indica `<>`.

Comment: El código está cortado. Los event listeners tienes que agregarlos una sola vez. Sino obtendrás efectos como por ejemplo, que el código se ejecutará más de una vez por cada que presiones el botón.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiene que asignarle un id a cada input y a sus botones. En este caso como son solo 5 inputs puede hacerlo de esa forma, pero si fueran una cantidad de inputs dinámica tendría que buscar otra manera de hacerlo, adjunto el ejemplo para 2 inputs:

```js
let btnrestaGrupoInput = document.querySelector('#btnrestaGrupoInput') //boton mas primer input
let btnsumaGrupoInput = document.querySelector('#btnsumaGrupoInput') //boton resta primer input
let grupoInput = document.querySelector('#grupoInput'); //muestra numero primer input
let btnrestaGrupoInput2 = document.querySelector('#btnrestaGrupoInput2') //boton resta segundo input
let btnsumaGrupoInput2 = document.querySelector('#btnsumaGrupoInput2') //boton mas segundo input
let grupoInput2 = document.querySelector('#grupoInput2'); //muestra numero segundo input


btnrestaGrupoInput.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    grupoInput.value=grupoInput.value - 1
});

btnsumaGrupoInput.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    grupoInput.value=parseInt(grupoInput.value) + 1
});

btnrestaGrupoInput2.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    grupoInput2.value=grupoInput2.value - 1
});

btnsumaGrupoInput2.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    grupoInput2.value=parseInt(grupoInput2.value) + 1
});
```

```html
  <form class="form_user" id="form_user">


        <label class="label" id="label" for="Horas">Horas</label>
        <button id="btnrestaGrupoInput" class="btnSignos">-</button><input class="input_form" id="grupoInput"
            type="number"  placeholder="0" autofocus min="0" value="25"><button
            class="btnSignos2" id="btnsumaGrupoInput">+</button>

        <label class="label" >Horas2</label>
        <button id="btnrestaGrupoInput2">-</button><input class="input_form" id="grupoInput2" type="number"
             placeholder="0" min="0" value="15"><button id="btnsumaGrupoInput2">+</button>


    

        <button class="cerrarModal" id="cerrarModal"><strong>Cancelar</strong></button>
        <input type="button" name="send" class="send_btnForm" id="send_btn" value="Anotar">

    </form>
```

Comment: me sirvió tu ayuda, la marque como correcta a tu respuesta muchas gracias